# Where can I find (digitized version if possible) an old film called "The World of The Talisman"?

Tags: the-world-of-the-talisman

When I was little, I used to own this film on VHS:

[image]

I'm pretty sure that the version I had was called **The Talisman**.

I'm trying to find it again, preferably a digital version so that I can burn it to disk, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. It's also coming up with different names when I search for it: **The Talisman**, **The World of The Talisman**, and **Birth**.

The version I owned was an American dub, and I'd love to find it again, as it is a film my brother and I used to always watch, so it has a lot of nostalgia.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, let's learn the different names and versions of the [English dubs of *Birth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth_%28anime%29#English_dubs).

> Two English dubs of *Birth* exist. The first was licensed in 1987 by Harmony Gold and released by Streamline Pictures in North America and the United Kingdom under the title *The World of the Talisman*. [...] The OVA was later retitled yet again to *Planet Busters*.

While the names are different, the content and dub of both versions are entirely the same.<sup>[[source]](http://www.anime-games.co.uk/VHS/anime/talisman.php)</sup>

> The second dub by ADV Films, released on DVD on July 13, 2004, is much more faithful to the original Japanese version.

The ADV release is titled *Birth: A War of Two Worlds!*, and there's a good [review](https://web.archive.org/web/20140315044219/http://www.mania.com/birth_article_76256.html) of the DVD.

You have two choices:

1. Get the [VHS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004U5K5) and digitize it yourself, or bring it to a Walgreens store (for example) and [ask them to do it for you](http://photo.walgreens.com/walgreens/storepage/storePageId=DVD+Transfer). This is the only option if you want to reminisce about the Harmony Gold's version which you owned.
2. Get the [DVD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00029NMIQ) directly, but remember that the content and dub of the ADV release are different from what you used to watch.

I also recommend a read of this [well-written post](https://washiblog.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/birth-classic-1984-ova-yoshinori-kanada/) on the OVA and the animators behind it.